# Does Dragon v2 only have Superdracos as an abort system?

Tags: spacex, abort, dragon-v2

The accepted answer to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9757/what-abort-modes-does-soyuz-have-in-space) states that the SAS Launch Escape System of a Soyuz spacecraft is used for aborts early in the ascend phase and it has a variety of abort modes after the SAS is jettisoned.

Since the SuperDracos of the Dragon v2 are to my understanding the equivalent to the SAS, what is used as an abort system after the point where Soyuz's SAS were to be jettisoned(after 157 seconds into the flight)? Are the SuperDracos the only abort system or does Dragon v2 have a variety of abort modes like the Soyuz does after the SAS is jettisoned?

Comment: For context, you need to understand that there is a difference between abort modes and abort systems. An abort mode can be something as simple as not docking to the ISS, but instead following re-entry procedures early. Soyuz does not have abort options throughout the entire descent, but will follow different options/modes depending on how far it is into the launch. Dragon V2 will do the same (Such as the software that would decouple from the 2nd stage and land using parachutes which has now been rushed into Dragon V1) and will also have various abort **modes** but not really abort **systems**

Comment: Do you have source that SpaceX is adding chutes in V1

Comment: Dragon 1 already has chutes that AR eased to return from the iss. Musk said that the software to deploy the chutes after a RUD would be included on Dragon 1 from the next flight onwards which would have saved the  CRS-7 payload. Dragon 2 will land on chutes initially until propulsive landing is certified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario for an abort with the Dragon V2 requires the use of the Super Draco pods to get far enough away from the rocket to prevent damage, following the use of parachutes to safely land. The parachutes are only used in an abort (Or otherwise atypical landing), as it takes longer to re-certify the parachutes after a landing than the rockets. The rockets are either used as an abort mechanism, or the primary landing system if there is no abort that occurs, thus they last all the way to the ground.

Note that if you achieve orbit, there are additional abort mechanisms, such as land without docking with the ISS.

Comment: AIUI since this post was written the plan of doing rocket-landings has been abandoned because it was too hard to convince NASA that it was safe. So the plan now is to use parachutes for all landings and use the superdracos only for aborts.

Answer (score 3):

The Super Draco pods provide launch abort capability all the way to orbit. They are not jettisoned since they are integrated into the frame of the spacecraft. This is less efficient but is negated by the large payload capacity of Falcon 9 and the opportunity to attempt propulsive landings which are critical to reuse. Since the super Draco is high thrust and and able to be throttled, it can provide a safe abort at any point in the flight to orbit. Elon Musk pointed this out in the Dragon 2 reveal.